# My window is changing size, is win32com.client affecting tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, win32com

When i activate my function by pressing the button to print a label with my dymo-printer the window is not only changing size but it also rescales and becomes very small. I've tried with other functions but it only happens with this script and I have no idea why.

```
import win32com.client as win
import pathlib

def print_label(case_id, name, room, phone_number):
    barcode_code = case_id
    qr_code = f"tel:+46-{phone_number[1:]}"
    information_person = f"""#{case_id}
    {name} - {room}"""

    label_path = pathlib.Path("./final.label")
    printer_com = win.Dispatch("Dymo.DymoAddIn")
    my_printer = printer_com.GetDymoPrinters()
    printer_com.SelectPrinter(my_printer)
    printer_com.Open(label_path)


    printer_label = win.Dispatch("Dymo.DymoLabels")
    printer_label.SetField("BARCODE", barcode_code)
    printer_label.SetField("BARCODE_1", qr_code)
    printer_label.SetField("ADDRESS", information_person)

    if True:
        printer_com.StartPrintJob()
        printer_com.Print(1,False)
        printer_com.EndPrintJob()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've checked trough the code and it seems like win32com.client.Dispatch("Dymo.DymoAddIn") is the problem but i have no idea why

Comment: I'm really curious to know what's causing the downscaling. It seems like pywintypes.com_error is affecting tkinter in some mystical way but i still don't know why.